# Shopify - Conditional for discount code

Tags: php, variables, shopify, liquid

I was wondering if its possible to print a message to the user when they apply a coupon to their cart, something like this:

```
{% if discount = testcoupon123 %} 
You will get a free item!
{% endif %}
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work please?

Comment: Try `{% if discount = 'testcoupon123' %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
{% for discount in discounts %}
   {% if discount.code = "testcoupon123" %} 
      You will get a free item!
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```